# how to include external models in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a problem when i want to include my models with mongoose in nodejs, i'm create a models with schema like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Users = new Schema({
    idUser  : {type:String},
    username: {type:String}
});

// middleware
Users.pre('save', function (next,done) {
  notify(this.get('email') + done);
  // something goes wrong
  next(new Error('something went wrong'));
});

//registered on mongoose models
mongoose.model("Users",Users);
```

and i save in folde models/schema.js
but i don't know how to call that file in app.js , when i'm try using this code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , models = require('./models/schema.js');

//mongoose configurationfor database;
var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/vynchat");
var users = mongoose.model("Users");
users.save();
```

i have error when i try to start `sudo node app.js`

```
throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Object function model() {
    Model.apply(this, arguments);
  } has no method 'save'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/development/vynapp/app.js:18:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

the error model() has no method save...
how i can fix this..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling `users.save();`, but, `users` is a **Model**.

The `save` methods can be used on instances of models, something like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , models = require('./models/schema');

var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/vynchat")
  , Users = mongoose.model("Users");


var user = new User({
      "your": "data"
    });

user.save(function (err, model) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log("My new User is saved",
    "`save` hook worked as espected since we had no errors here");
});
```

You should read the node.js [modules API](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) and carefully read [mongoose API](http://mongoosejs.com/).

As a side note: when you `require('mongoose')` the first time in your code node will give you an instance of the mongoose connector, subsequent requires will yield the same object.

Comment: i have been fix my code before, but the new problem is i can get return from my method on schema file, `Users.methods.getId = function(models,id){
    models.findById( id, function (err, found) {
      return found.username;
    });
}` and in my app.js i'm place this code `var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/vynchat');
var Users = conn.model('Users', Users);
var m = new Users();
console.log(m.getId(Users,"4f50914da314c150cf000001"));`  the result is undefined, but if i'm `console.log(found.username)` in file schema the result is true; how can i fix that..

Comment: `getId` is performing an asynchronous task (`models.findById`), then trying to return the result using `return`. Such is why callbacks were invented. See [this post](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing schema object param while creating model object.
Do this:

```
var users_model = mongoose.model("Users", YourSchemaObject);
var User_Document = new user_model();
User_Document.field_name = 'value'; //here you can access getter/setter/methods
User_Document.save();
```

Comment: i'm using construct for creating object ...^_^